# How was privacy considered prior to the 20th century?

Tags: social-history

People seem to have become increasingly more concerned in the 20th century about privacy and their personal information. It's also been the time when people in many countries have had the opportunity for personal space and private rooms.

Before people had their own designated private space, did people still have the desire for privacy? I've heard that people were at ease having sex in front of others. Was there a different idea about what it meant? How did people feel about sharing personal thoughts and feelings and having those shared amongst the community?

I'm looking for answers about the social history, though if laws back it up I'm interested in that too. I'd also be interested to hear about relevant books and papers.

Comment: You'll generally get a better answer if you document your preliminary research.  What have you found so far?

Comment: Would you like to limit this question a bit in terms of geography and time period? Not every contemporary culture would view privacy in the same way, let alone across multiple centuries. For that matter, why tag early-medieval and renaissance? That's oddly discontinuous.

Comment: I've removed the tags: either be broad or specific, but can't be specific in two completely different areas: pick one or the other (or none! but not both).

Comment: I think this would be legitimate if we specified a time and space. Roman views of privacy are going to be different than Imperial Chinese.  Heck, Roman views may change as they evolve from Republic to Principate to Dominate.  All will be different from the view held by the Lenni Lenapi or the Anasazi.